# Dropdown list to a range of cells across the worksheets

Tags: excel-2010

I have a drop-down list for cells A1 to A150. I need the same drop-down to appear across all worksheets in the file for same range (A1 to A150). 
I'm defining list in a separate worksheet in the same file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select Range A1:A150 on your first worksheet (where you have applied the validation) and press Ctrl-C to copy it.
2. Click the tab of the first of your empty sheets, hold shift and
   click the last one (they'll all be selected & white).
3. Select A1 and click Home > the arrow below Paste > Paste Special and select
   Validation.